# Android studio not responsive when java functions added

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio

```
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String viewname =  bundle.getString("data1");
    String viewphone =  bundle.getString("data2");
    String viewheight = bundle.getString("data3");

    String viewweight = bundle.getString("data4");
    textViewPro = findViewById(R.id.textViewProfile);
    textViewPro.setText("Name: "+viewname+"\n\nPhone: 
    "+viewphone+"\n\nHeight: "+viewheight+"CM \n\nWeight: 
    "+viewweight+"KG\n");
```

Comment: Is your `String` in `setText()` if they are exactly the same of this try `setText()` on one line.

Comment: If you are getting an error, add the stacktrace to the question.